# Finding a second solution to $ty'' - 4y' +4t^3y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem provides $\sin(t^2)$ as a solution to the differential equation $$ty'' - y' +4t^3y = 0$$

and asks for a second, independent solution.

Dividing the entire equation by $t$ to isolate $y''$ provided me with the following result by Abel's theorem $$W(y_1,y_2)(t) = c \cdot exp \big(\int \frac{1}{t} \cdot dt\big)$$

From which the following equality can be applied

$$\sin(t^2)y_2'-2t\cos(t^2)y_2 = ct$$

From this point on I am unsure of how to isolate $y_2$. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplification that you provide does the job. Now, observe that this equation is same as:
$$\left(\frac{y_2}{\sin {t^2}}\right)' = \frac{ct}{({\sin t^2})^2}$$ Now, you can integrate both sides easily.
Also, a general way of solving these problems( second order odes), is by variation of parameters, i.e. substituting $y = c_1*y_1$, where $y_1$ is the given solution, and $c_1$ is a function of $t$. The equation simplifies by using the fact that $y_1$ is a given solution, i.e. $ty_1''-4y_1'+4t^3y_1 = 0$